# primefaces3.0 X-scale value change

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jqplot

I'm implementing line charts of primefaces(3.0) , I'm trying to change the value of X-scale

The values which I'm using are minX="0" maxX="38" , since primefaces linecharts is using jqplot , I added this script

```
<script>
           $(function(){
               widget_category.plot.axes.xaxis._tickInterval = 1;
               widget_category.plot.axes.xaxis.numberTicks = 38;

           });
</script>
```

But still the coordinates is coming in decimals.

I would like to mention that for Y scale, the values I used are minY="40" maxY="110" with style="height:1005px;" , As i figured out for a scale value , which can be 10 if height is defined as 1005px i.e.  5 * 14 = 70 which means Y scale is of 5 intervals , with 14 values and the line height is 1005 as 5*14*14 = 980 + 25 (which is top-margin added) 1005.

Though the same is not working out for X-Scale.

Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic in your Y values are all multiplication operations on whole numbers, which will always result in a whole number.  These whole numbers correlate perfectly to pixels.

Your X range however involves a multiplication of `1.0` and `38`, one being an integer value and the other being determined as a float or double number.  When performing a multiplication operation where one number is a float then the result value will always be a float, and standard floating point artithmetic rules will apply.  This is why the coordinates are coming in decimals which don't equate perfectly to pixels.

When using Javascript you need to be careful of these kinds of pitfalls because it is not a strongly typed language like Java and it will not point things like this out to you.